# Conditionnel vs subjonctif après pronom relatif

Tags: subjonctif, conditionnel

Je cherche un étudiant qui pourrait arroser mes plantes pendant les vacances.

et

Je cherche un étudiant qui puisse arroser mes plantes pendant les vacances.

Est-ce que les deux phrases sont différentes?

Dites moi les différences même si elles sont tres petites s'il vous plaît.

Comment: Les deux sont correctes. La première est plus naturelle maintenant. Pas de différence de sens.

Comment: @Frank Je pense qu'elle te semble plus naturelle parce que le français a tendance à vouloir éviter le subjonctif, mais les deux expriment un degré (très léger, certes) de certitude différent.

Comment: @None - Peux-tu expliquer cette différence? Pour moi, _qui puisse_ paraît plus général, on met l'accent sur cette capacité de l'étudiant, alors que _qui pourrait_ met plutôt l'accent sur la temporalité de l'action?

Comment: @Frank Voir [BDL](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25168/la-grammaire/le-verbe/modes/subjonctif/subjonctif-et-subordonnee-relative) : « Il y a des contextes où le subjonctif, le futur et le présent de l’indicatif ainsi que le conditionnel peuvent s’employer, avec des nuances de sens indiquant une plus ou moins grande éventualité dans la réalisation de l’action ». Le conditionnel est le + improbable (et le présent le plus probable bien sûr).

Comment: @None - intéressant - ce n'est pas tout à fait comme ça que je le ressens. lkl ci-dessous a aussi un ressenti plus proche du mien, apparemment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Je cherche un étudiant qui pourrait arroser mes plantes pendant les vacances.

Je sais que cette personne existe.

> Je cherche un étudiant qui puisse arroser mes plantes pendant les vacances.

Je ne suis pas sûr que cette personne existe.